# UITableView pagination with section data

Tags: uitableview, xamarin.ios

I have a table view that the data is grouped based on a status field. I got the grouped data showing up correctly but I have a problem and it's with paging.

On a non-grouped UITableView I have it looking at the rows and when it hits a threshold I invoke an event to grab more data from the API, that idea didn't seem to work with grouped data.

I tried looking around but I can't find anything on pagination with grouped data.

Comment: Does my answer work for you?

Comment: for the most part yes it did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's almost same as non-grouped `UITableView`, in a grouped `UITableView`, you have to check the `last section` first and the check if the row is the `last row` in that section:

```
public class myDelegate : UITableViewDelegate {

    Dictionary<string, List<TableItem>> indexedTableItems;
    string[] keys;

    public myDelegate(List<TableItem> items) {

        indexedTableItems = new Dictionary<string, List<TableItem>>();
        foreach (var t in items)
        {
            if (indexedTableItems.ContainsKey(t.SubHeading))
            {
                indexedTableItems[t.SubHeading].Add(t);
            }
            else
            {
                indexedTableItems.Add(t.SubHeading, new List<TableItem>() { t });
            }
        }
        keys = indexedTableItems.Keys.ToArray();
    }

    public override void WillDisplay(UITableView tableView, UITableViewCell cell, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        List<TableItem> tabItems = indexedTableItems[keys[indexPath.Section]];

        if (indexPath.Section == keys.Length-1 && indexPath.Row == tabItems.Count-1)
        {
            loadmoreData();
        }
    }

    public void loadmoreData() {

        Console.WriteLine("loadmoreData");
    }
}
```

I uploaded my sample project [here](https://github.com/XfHua/GroupedTableView-loadMore) and feel free to ask me any question.

Comment: Thanks, that was the missing link for me